# How does fan-out change circuit complexity?

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits

Edit: Here's maybe a clearer presentation of my question. In a Boolean formula, all the gates have fan-out 1, and the graph representing the formula is a tree. In a Boolean circuit, the gates can have multiple outputs. What can be said about formula size as compared to circuit size?

I am learning some basics about classical circuit complexity, and have a confusion centering around the role of fan-out.

In various references (e.g. the textbook by Vollmer), circuit size is defined with respect to a basis where each gate has fan-out 1, like say AND, OR and NOT. A natural, simple operation seems to me to be fan-out, where I just copy a bit so it can be used twice in the circuit.

I am wondering how allowing fan-out changes the size of a minimal circuit computing a Boolean function.

A naive observation is that if I have a circuit of depth d that uses fan-out (say with two outputs), I could replace it with a circuit without fan-out while increasing the circuit size by at most $2^d$ (make a copy of the circuit below each fan-out, to compute that bit twice). Unless $d$ is $O(\log n)$ for $n$ the input size, this changes a polynomial size circuit to a super-polynomial one, so at least using this observation alone fan-out seems to have a notable effect on circuit size.

Is there a better way to remove fan-out gates than the above? Or is there a motivation for focusing on notions of circuit size  / complexity that exclude fan-out?

Comment: What, formally and for above question, is a *gate*? What are *gates in a Boolean formula*, *formula size*, *circuit size*, *fan-out*? I remember [fan-out](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan-out) of a gate as the number of "standard" inputs it is able to drive (within specs).

Answer (score 1):

Restricting fan-out is crucial in [reversible computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing), in which duplicating values is impossible. This is related to quantum computing.

Another circuit model without fan-out which has been studied recently is *comparator circuits*, see for example Mayr and Subramanian, [The complexity of circuit value and network stability](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002200009290024D) or the more recent [The complexity of the comparator circuit value problem](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Esacook/homepage/lfmmToct.pdf). Comparator circuits are not expected to be P-complete, and in particular, are expected to be weaker than circuits which do allow fan-out. See [Comparator Circuits over Finite Bounded Posets](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2015/035/revision/1/download/) for what happens when we allow the wires to carry values from different posets (rather than the Boolean lattice $\{0,1\}$).